# Get number of hits for APC cache entry

Tags: php, caching, apc

Is there an undocumented method to call to get number of hits that a cache variable had? Something like `apc_variable_info('cache_key')`.

I realize there is `apc_cache_info()`, which returns the list of variables which in turn contains number of hits for each variable, however I have thousands of variables and I need to check number of hits on almost every cache *fetch* request, as the number of hits will determine whenever the variable should be flushed and fresh data should be generated and stored.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do, is (once per page/whatever view) calculate the hits for each variable using `apc_cache_info`, then use a wrapper function for `apc_fetch` to decide whether or not to refresh.

Other than that, I am not aware of anything that could solve your problem.